# Simplest solution to replace a tiny file inside an MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, orca, msitransform

Many of our customers have access to InstallShield, WISE or AdminStudio. These aren't a problem. I'm hoping there is some way I can provide our smaller customers **without access to commercial repackaging tools** a freely available set of tools and steps to do the file replacement themselves.

Only need to replace a single configuration file inside a compressed MSI, the target user can be assumed to already have Orca installed, know how to use this to customize the Property table (to embed license details for GPO deployment) and have generated an MST file.

**Disclaimer**: *this is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer) but both questions and answers in that thread are not clear.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, revisiting this question with my own answer providing nice little VB script that will do all heavy lifting. As mentioned in the original question, the aim was provide a simple solution for sysadmin users to make the updates/changes themselves.

Below is a simplified version of the code I'm currently providing to customers

```vb
Option Explicit

Const MY_CONFIG = "MyConfigApp.xml"
Const CAB_FILE = "config.cab"
Const MSI = "MyApp.msi"

Dim filesys : Set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If filesys.FileExists("temp.tmp") Then filesys.DeleteFile("temp.tmp")
filesys.CopyFile MSI, "temp.tmp"

Dim installer, database, database2, view
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase ("temp.tmp", 1)
Set database2 = installer.OpenDatabase (MSI, 1)

If Not filesys.FileExists(MY_CONFIG) Then WScript.Quit 2 ' No config file, abort!

Dim objFile, size, result, seq, objCab

' MakeCab object has been depreciated so we fallback to makecab.exe for with Windows 7
On Error Resume Next ' Disable error handling, for a moment
Set objCab = CreateObject("MakeCab.MakeCab.1") 
On Error Goto 0  ' Turn error handling back on

If IsObject(objCab) Then ' Object creation successful - use XP method   
    objCab.CreateCab CAB_FILE, False, False, False
    objCab.AddFile MY_CONFIG, filesys.GetFileName(MY_CONFIG)
    objCab.CloseCab
    Set objCab = Nothing
Else ' object creation failed - try Windows 7 method
    Dim WshShell, oExec
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("makecab " & filesys.GetFileName(MY_CONFIG) & " " & CAB_FILE)
End If

Set objFile = filesys.GetFile(MY_CONFIG)
size = objFile.Size

Set view = database.OpenView ("SELECT LastSequence FROM Media WHERE DiskId = 1")
view.Execute
Set result = view.Fetch
seq = result.StringData(1) + 1 ' Sequence for new configuration file

Set view = database.OpenView ("INSERT INTO Media (DiskId, LastSequence, Cabinet) VALUES ('2', '" & seq & "', '" & CAB_FILE & "')")
view.Execute

Set view = database.OpenView ("UPDATE File SET FileSize = " & size & ", Sequence = " & seq & ", FileName = 'MYC~2.CNF|MyConfigApp.xml' WHERE File = '" & MY_CONFIG & "'")
view.Execute

database.GenerateTransform database2, "CustomConfig.mst"
database.CreateTransformSummaryInfo database2, "CustomConfig.mst", 0, 0
filesys.DeleteFile("temp.tmp")

Set view = nothing
Set installer = nothing
Set database = nothing
Set database2 = nothing
Set filesys = Nothing
WScript.Quit 0
```

**Update:** The *MakeCab.MakeCab.1* object has been depreciated, code updated to now work with Windows 7.

Comment: Can you explain: MY_CONFIG is file what you want to replace and CAB_FILE is media file inside the MSI... correct?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO this kind of scenario indicates a missing feature in the application being installed, and is easier to fix in the application than hacking around with the MSI.

---

### Admin Image

Let me first say that a simple way to "solve" this for your users, is to tell them to run an Admin Installation of your MSI. This will essentially extract all the files from the internal CABs and put all files in the specified folder:

***msiexec.exe /a myinstaller.msi TARGETDIR=C:\AdminImage***

Your users can then go directly into the extracted folder structure and update the file in question and then map the directory to other PC's and install the MSI. There could be side effects to this relating to the file having a hash value in the MSI (to avoid spoofing), but in most cases it works fine.

---

### Run XML XPath Query

New versions of deployment tools such as Installshield and Wix feature built-in support for running XPath queries during the installation and hence write sections dynamically.

---

### Application Update

Setting up an application on a PC involves several steps. First there is the deployment of content to the machine - this should be done using an MSI, no question about it. However, in most advanced applications several "post installation configuration tasks" similar to this "config file update" are required.

It is almost always better to defer these configuration tasks until the **application launch**, rather than to implement features in the MSI. There are many reasons for this, but the most important being that only the application EXE will be guaranteed to run in the correct user context. MSI files can be run with system rights, a different user account or via some other mechanism.

What we generally recommend is to use the MSI to **get all required content onto the PC**. Then tag the registry to indicate to the application that it's the first launch (for updates, you can increment a counter or write the new version number to HKLM). Then the application can perform the final configuration steps in its startup routine. It can copy a default config.xml file from somewhere in %ProgramFiles% and copy it to the user profile. Then it can read required values from HKLM written by the MSI, and then update the config.xml file with these values.

In general: avoid configuration steps performed by MSI or any other setup mechanism. Concentrate on writing the required files and registry items to the machine, and then let the application itself set up a proper runtime environment. This will allow much better deployment control. It is better "Encapsulation" if you like. The MSI sends a "message" to the application via the registry, and the application knows "how to set itself up correctly" based on the messages.

Comment: In my case, I'm updating the global "default config" in the AllUsers/AppData folder. Copying to the per-user location happens at first launch. The configuration file is binary data in a proprietary format, it's not post-installation configuration at all - it's setting defaults for when the post-installation first-run configuration takes place (once a user config exists, the system default config is ignored). The question was originally asked as it's a simple drag/drop operation to do this in InstallShield, but we've migrated to WiX and needed to provide a easy way for our customers to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I asume that you create the msi file yourself (?)

When you use [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to generate your msi, the customer can simply regenerate the whole msi after replacing the file (wix is free). Otherwise it should be possible to use an uncompressed file which is not embedded in the msi. In wix you have to add a [media element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_media.htm) without a cabinet attribute. The disadvantage is that you have to distribute two files, instead of a single msi.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an entry to the [Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369801.aspx) table, adding another medium with no cabinet file, and a LastSequence one more than the CAB file's last sequence. You then need to replace in the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596(VS.85).aspx) table the file's sequence with the new file, and update all the other file attributes that may have changed.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, when adding a medium with no cabinet file I get "Error 2920. Source directory not specified for file <filename>"

However it *does* work if I use a cabinet file.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following post:
[How to replace a file in a msi installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer)

Where is mentionned:

This command extracts the MSI files:
msi2xml -c OutputDir TestMSI.MSI

Open OutputDir and modify the file.

To rebuild the MSI run:
xml2msi.exe -m TestMSI.xml

You need the -m to ignore the 'MD5 checksum test' that fails when an MSIs file(s) are modified.

Download:
https://msi2xml.sourceforge.io/