# File from msi location

Tags: wix, windows-installer, location

I would like to copy file that placed near the msi to the program file folder.

I have the next code in my project:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="Global.txt">
  <Component Id="Global.txt" Guid="263B6F39-BE6B-4b51-8AE4-4D152436F0AE" DiskId="2" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <File Name="Global.txt" Source="./Global.txt" Compressed="no" DiskId="2"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

The problem is – that an empty file named Global.txt need to be placed at the development machine in order to build the msi.

Is there an elegant solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The filesize and modification date is hashed and embedded in the MSI, you will need to update the MSI post-build if you're looking to have your customers edit the Global.txt after the MSI has been created.

See [Simplest solution to replace a tiny file inside an MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319894/simplest-solution-to-replace-a-tiny-file-inside-an-msi) for one solution.