# Read an external settings/parameters file from installer project?

Tags: installation, parameters, settings

I have created an installer project in VS2008 and need to supply a settings/parameters file along with the .msi/exe file; is this possible? The settingsfile will basically contain some information that is needed in the configuration and our different clients can control the settingsfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted some code we use to insert an updated config file to an existing MSI before our customers deploy across the network. Code at [Simplest solution to replace a tiny file inside an MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319894/simplest-solution-to-replace-a-tiny-file-inside-an-msi)

Comment: Thanx, this is the most elegant solution I have seen for this challenge. Will use this in future projects. What we ended up with was just shipping with a .bat and .xml file, inputting the path for the .xml file when running the install.

Comment: Happy to help! That question has been updated a few times (and will continue to be) as I've found easier/better/more elegant ways to do things.