# How to update assemblies in existing MSI?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2009, orca

We have existing MSI created using InstallShield 9.0. This MSI installs some .NET assemblies in target installation directory.

We have changed some functionality of application and so a few assemblies have been changed. Now we want to edit/update the MSI to have the latest of those modified assemblies. How to do it now?

Can Orca be used for it? If yes, can you point me to some useful link where I can find instructions/guide?

If someone can guide in editing MSM (merge module) using Orca, even that would be fine.

Note: We need to edit existing MSI due to strange request from customer. Otherwise, releasing a patch is good option, I know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that because of the way MSI works the answer will be "yes, but it would be a bad idea".  Why can you not just rebuild your InstallShield MSI project using the new assembly?

Comment: @Justin: +1 for your comment. I agree with you but due to some reasons we need to update the existing one instead of rebuilding new one. Can you please help on that ?

Comment: As Cosmin mentioned, you would need to update the information in File Table, CAB archives; modification to Components table could be required. Repackaging with the updated files and keeping the ProductCode is the simplest solution, if the number of files to update is more than 3–5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used many links to get a solution. All helpful links are shared below.

http://developermax.blogspot.com/2011/02/msi.html

http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/158-how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-large-msi-4-ways

[How to replace a file in a msi installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer)

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/112121-makecab-everything-in-a-folder/

http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?t=182791

[Simplest solution to replace a tiny file inside an MSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319894/simplest-solution-to-replace-a-tiny-file-inside-an-msi)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply edit the MSI because file information is stored in multiple places in your installer (File table, Components table, CAB archives etc.).

The recommended approach is to create a new version of your installer as a [major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Basically, in your original InstallShield project you increase the Product Version and change the Product Code.

This way your new installer will automatically uninstall the old one. Whatever request your client has, a new version shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I agree with you. But could you please help in editing the "existing" one? That's a strange thing but customer demand after all ! :)

Comment: Editing the existing MSI to modify source files is not feasible. You can try rebuilding your old project with the new files.