# Update msi installer from msiexec.exe command line

Tags: windows-installer

I have msi installer and now I want to update or add a text file in to installer from msiexec.exe . How I can do it?

I am able to extract it from following command :

msiexec /a  c:\abc.msi TARGETDIR=C:\EXTRACTHERE /qn

But now I want create a MSI again after inserting a new text  file .Is there any reverse command?

Any one can help me?

Comment: See http://tekunik.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/how-to-add-file-to-msi-with-orca.html

Comment: Hi ..thanks for giving the link. But I need a command for msiexec.exe

Comment: msiexec.exe can't do it. Use something suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer

Answer (score 0):

No, once you create an administrative installation there is no way to turn it back into a single MSI.  You could create a utility that uses the underlying APIs to create a new MSI but you'd lose the original digital signatures if present.

Comment: It has not any digital signature. Can you give me a command to  turn  back into a single MSI.

Comment: As I said, there is no "command".  You'd have to write a program to do it.

Comment: I have actually done this using Wise for Windows Installer. I added a file to the extracted files, and saved the admin image MSI. This cased an external cab file to be created. It does some magic in the Media and Cab tables and juggles the extracted files and the cabbed one and installs ok. You can also hack the Media and Cab tables and use the file directly from the extracted media, but I don't have sample files here and this is complex. I think I even used an MST once to add the extracted file and applied it to several admin images to add the same file, hacky but worked well.