# Adding cabinet file to msi programatically with DTF (wix)

Tags: c#, wix, cab, dtf

**Introduction to the Task at hand:** *can be skipped if impatient*

The company I work for is not a software company, but focus on mechanical and thermodynamic engineering problems.
To help solve their system design challenges, they have developed a software for calculating the system impact of replacing individual components.
The software is quite old, written in FORTRAN and has evolved over a period of 30 years, which means that we cannot quickly re-write it or update it.

As you may imagine the way this software is installed has also evolved, but significantly slower than the rest of the system, meaning that packaging is done by a batch script that gathers files from different places, and puts them in a folder, which is then compiled into an iso, burned to a cd, and shipped with mail.

You young programmers (I am 30), may expect a program to load dll's, but otherwise be fairly self-contained after linking. Even if the code is made up of several classes, from different namespaces etc..

In FORTRAN 70 however.. Not so much. Which means that the software it self consists of an alarming number of calls to prebuilt modules (read: *seperate programs*)..

We need to be able to distribute via the internet, as any other modern company have been able to for a while. To do this we could just make the *.iso downloadable right?

Well, unfortunately no, the iso contains several files which are user specific.
As you may imagine with thousands of users, that would be thousands of isos, that are nearly identical.

Also we wan't to convert the old FORTRAN based installation software, into a real installation package, and all our other (and more modern) programs are C# programs packaged as MSI's..
But the compile time for a single msi with this old software on our server, is close to 10 seconds, so it is simply not an option for us to build the msi, when requested by the user. (if multiple users requests at the same time, the server won't be able to complete before requests timeout..)
Nor can we prebuild the user specific msi's and cache them, as we would run out of memory on the server.. (total at ~15 giga Byte per released version)

**Task Description** *tl:dr;*

Here is what I though I would do: (inspired by comments from [Christopher Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200936/christopher-painter))

- Create a base MSI, with dummy files instead of the the user specific files
- Create cab file for each user, with the user specific files
- At request time inject the userspecific cab file into a temporary copy of the base msi using the "_Stream" *table*.
- Insert a reference into the Media table with a new 'DiskID' and a 'LastSequence' corresponding to the extra files, and the name of the injected cabfile.
- Update the Filetable with the name of the user specific file in the new cab file, a new Sequence number (in the range of the new cab files sequence range), and the file size.

**Question**

My code fails to do the task just described. I can read from the msi just fine, but the cabinet file is never inserted.

*Also:*

If I open the msi with DIRECT mode, it corrupts the media table, <strike>and if I open it in TRANSACTION mode, it fails to change anything at all..</strike>

In direct mode the existing line in the Media table is replaced with:

```
DiskId: 1
LastSequence: -2145157118
Cabinet: "Name of action to invoke, either in the engine or the handler DLL."
```

*What Am I doing wrong ?*

Below I have provided the snippets involved with injecting the new cab file.

snippet 1

```
public string createCabinetFileForMSI(string workdir, List<string> filesToArchive)
    {
        //create temporary cabinet file at this path:
        string GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string cabFile = GUID + ".cab";
        string cabFilePath = Path.Combine(workdir, cabFile);

        //create a instance of Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.CabInfo
        //which provides file-based operations on the cabinet file
        CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(cabFilePath);

        //create a list with files and add them to a cab file
        //now an argument, but previously this was used as test:
        //List<string> filesToArchive = new List<string>() { @"C:\file1", @"C:\file2" };
        cab.PackFiles(workdir, filesToArchive, filesToArchive);

        //we will ned the path for this file, when adding it to an msi..
        return cabFile;
    }
```

snippet 2

```
    public int insertCabFileAsNewMediaInMSI(string cabFilePath, string pathToMSIFile, int numberOfFilesInCabinet = -1)
    {
        //open the MSI package for editing
        pkg = new InstallPackage(pathToMSIFile, DatabaseOpenMode.Direct); //have also tried direct, while database was corrupted when writing.
        return insertCabFileAsNewMediaInMSI(cabFilePath, numberOfFilesInCabinet);
    }
```

snippet 3

```
 public int insertCabFileAsNewMediaInMSI(string cabFilePath, int numberOfFilesInCabinet = -1)
    {
        if (pkg == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot insert cabinet file into non-existing MSI package. Please Supply a path to the MSI package");
        }

        int numberOfFilesToAdd = numberOfFilesInCabinet;
        if (numberOfFilesInCabinet < 0)
        {
            CabInfo cab = new CabInfo(cabFilePath);
            numberOfFilesToAdd = cab.GetFiles().Count;
        }

        //create a cab file record as a stream (embeddable into an MSI)
        Record cabRec = new Record(1);
        cabRec.SetStream(1, cabFilePath);

        /*The Media table describes the set of disks that make up the source media for the installation.
          we want to add one, after all the others
          DiskId - Determines the sort order for the table. This number must be equal to or greater than 1,
          for out new cab file, it must be > than the existing ones...
        */
        //the baby SQL service in the MSI does not support "ORDER BY `` DESC" but does support order by..
        IList<int> mediaIDs = pkg.ExecuteIntegerQuery("SELECT `DiskId` FROM `Media` ORDER BY `DiskId`");
        int lastIndex = mediaIDs.Count - 1;
        int DiskId = mediaIDs.ElementAt(lastIndex) + 1;

        //wix name conventions of embedded cab files is "#cab" + DiskId + ".cab"
        string mediaCabinet = "cab" + DiskId.ToString() + ".cab";

        //The _Streams table lists embedded OLE data streams.
        //This is a temporary table, created only when referenced by a SQL statement.
        string query = "INSERT INTO `_Streams` (`Name`, `Data`) VALUES ('" + mediaCabinet + "', ?)";
        pkg.Execute(query, cabRec);
        Console.WriteLine(query);

        /*LastSequence - File sequence number for the last file for this new media.
          The numbers in the LastSequence column specify which of the files in the File table
          are found on a particular source disk.

          Each source disk contains all files with sequence numbers (as shown in the Sequence column of the File table)
          less than or equal to the value in the LastSequence column, and greater than the LastSequence value of the previous disk
          (or greater than 0, for the first entry in the Media table).
          This number must be non-negative; the maximum limit is 32767 files.
          /MSDN
         */
        IList<int> sequences = pkg.ExecuteIntegerQuery("SELECT `LastSequence` FROM `Media` ORDER BY `LastSequence`");
        lastIndex = sequences.Count - 1;
        int LastSequence = sequences.ElementAt(lastIndex) + numberOfFilesToAdd;

        query = "INSERT INTO `Media` (`DiskId`, `LastSequence`, `Cabinet`) VALUES (" + DiskId.ToString() + "," + LastSequence.ToString() + ",'#" + mediaCabinet + "')";
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        pkg.Execute(query);

        return DiskId;

    }
```

update: stupid me, forgot about "committing" in transaction mode - but now it does the same as in direct mode, so no real changes to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this my self, since I just learned something about DIRECT mode that I didn't know before, and wan't to keep it here to allow for the eventual re-google..

Apparently we only succesfully updates the MSI, if we closed the database handle before the program eventually chrashed.

for the purpose of answering the question, this destructor should do it.

```
~className()
{
        if (pkg != null)
        {
            try
            {
                pkg.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //rollback not included as we edit directly?

                //do nothing.. 
                //atm. we just don't want to break anything if database was already closed, without dereferencing
            }
        }
}
```

after adding the correct close statement, the MSI grew in size
(and a media row was added to the media table :)    )

I will post the entire class for solving this task, when its done and tested,
but I'll do it in the related question on SO.
[the related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer)

Comment: I highly suggest using() statements in your code to call IDispose when the objects go out of space. DTF will close and clean all your resources for you avoiding these problems.

Comment: Noted, and thanks for the heads up.
As an embedded programmer by trade, the fancy new tricks in C# is unfamilliar, but not unwelcomed

Comment: BTW I meant scope not space.  I understand... I'm a build/release focal expert who's dabbled in a dozen languages over the last twenty years but never became an expert in any of them.  I only learn enough to understand the technologies and what developers build/release needs are.

Comment: Because I did elsewhere, just follow the link to the other question

Comment: Hi Henrik, Thanks but i want to know after inserting a cabinet file into the MSI, How to read this file during installation? note, i use WIX toolset. thanks for your help

Comment: That is an interesting problem in general, but it is, in fact not treated in this question / answer. You could make a new question on SO, or use the approach described in this question:  *see* the section "Task Description" in the question.   - I assume you would have to write code that either: uses PROPERTIES to do some actions, like extract the cab file at certain location, (it  cannot be rolled back by the installer). or make this presetned code edit the msi tables, and add references to the files directly using mediaID and sequence numbers etc..

Comment: Hi Henrik, Could you clarify more?

Comment: not in a comment, as it will take up to much space. Please create a question, and someone (perhaps me) will answer it. you can direct me there ;)

Comment: Hi Henrik, I already created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427006/wix-adding-and-reading-cabinet-file-to-msi-installer-programatically-with-dtf

Comment: and waiting your help as soon as possible