# Replace a file in an uncompressed setup

Tags: windows-installer, orca

Using InstallShield I have created a Basic MSI setup that its files are **uncompressed**
Now I would like to replace one of the text files in the setup without rebuilding the MSI again.
Can it be done without any worry  when running install, uninstall etc. ?
Is there some kind of size \ CKSUM check that compare data in msi with the actual file ?

Or it will be more reliable to edit the MSI with ORCA and remove this file from the file table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by making use of a tool named MsiFiler.
Replace the file in your extracted image and then run MsiFiler as outlined in :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370108(v=vs.85).aspx

Another way would be to make use of a tool like msi2xml and xml2msi to rebuild your msi package. 
There are a lot of examples here:

[How to replace a file in a msi installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer)

Hope this helps

Comment: But what if the files are uncompressed ? is it safe to replace the file ?
Does InstallShield \ MSI somehow save the files size\date\checksum and compare the info with the files being installed ?

Comment: @Epligam: It should be fine. You should be able to update the attributes of the file in the File table as well as the MsiFileHash table using a tool from the windows installer SDK named : MsiFiler.exe. Does this explain your question?

Comment: Back to this old issue, do I need to use this tool if I just want to replace a file in a setup which is already uncompressed ? it's a file that don't have a version like .pdf and .txt.

Comment: @Epligam Yes, you need to because for unversioned files, the hash is saved in the MsiFileHash table.