# Build/Release flow on VSTS with MSI deployed desktop app using configuration transforms

Tags: c#, windows-installer, azure-devops, app-config, desktop-application

We are in the process of implementing a DevOps strategy for our client deployed desktop app (winforms).  Until now, we used SlowCheetah to do our config transforms (ex: select QA from config manager, app.QA.config is automatically swapped in, do the build, deploy MSI to QA machines with SCCM).

We are trying to leverage Azure DevOps to automate this process and I have run into a roadblock.  I want to do 1 build, and a release pipeline of Dev --> QA --> UA --> Prod, but since the config transform is only run on build Im not sure how to do this.

The MSI would only be generated for the current selected config, so the drop in the release step would only have 1 MSI (with the config already packaged and no way to change it).

I know having the build step build the solution 4 times (one for each config) would work - the drop would contain all 4 MSIs, but that seems silly.

I can't just build the setup project on the release pipeline either as only the DLLs are available in the Drop, not the project files.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but just a thought. I ran into the same issue before a while back and we decided to do all the configuration that varied per environment in code and switch when pressing a "secret" key combination.  Extra value was that it did allows to change the configuration at runtime for every installation, also when (f.e.) reproducing an issue at a client. Depending on your scenario this might be possible or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem building MSIs from a Visual Studio solution that contained a WiX Installer project, using config transforms on the app.config to replace the configuration.

As you suggested, we originally went down the route of running an Azure DevOps build pipeline with multiple builds for every configuration in the solution, but this quickly became inelegant and wasteful as not only did we require builds for (dev/stage/qa/live) but also had configurations that applied to multiple customers, which ended up in 12 + configurations in the solution and really long build times.

### Replace config within the MSI

The solution we ended up with, as alluded to in a previous answer, was to build the MSI only once in a build pipeline, copy the MSI along with all our replacement app.config files to the drop folder, and then run a custom application within the release pipelines to forcibly replace the Application.exe.config inside the MSI. Unfortunately, this isn't as simple as just 'unzipping the MSI', replacing the config and then 're-zipping' within a release task because the MSI uses a custom file format and maintains an internal database that needs to be modified properly.

We ended up creating a custom C# .NET console application using the method posted in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560372/465921), which we then hosted on our on-premises build agent so that we could run a simple powershell task within our release pipeline that called our custom console application with some relevant parameters:

```
"C:\BuildTools\msi_replace_file.exe" -workingfolder "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_BuildOutput/drop/Application.Installer/bin/Release/" -msi "Application.Installer.msi" -config "Application.exe.config"
```

We then had a release pipeline stage for each 'configuration' that performed these basic steps:

[image: Release Pipeline]

There are various other methods for replacing a file in an MSI, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer), but we chose to create a C# application using the utilities within the Microsoft.Deployment.* namespace that are provided as part of the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). This would guarantee compatibility with the version of WiX we were using to build our installer in the first place and gave us full control of the process. However, I appreciate that this approach is quite brittle (which I'm not happy about) and not especially scalable as its relying on a custom tool to be hosted on our on-premises build agent. I intend to improve this in the future.

You should also be aware that hacking the MSI in this way could cause problems in the future, especially if you change your tool-chain or upgrade to a later version of WiX.

### Building the MSI from the release pipeline

I do not personally like the idea of copying the required dlls/assets to the drop location and then 'building' the MSIs within the release pipeline, because for us the act of building the WiX project was very much part of our 'build process' and was integrated into our visual studio solution, so it felt like moving the creation of the MSI to the release pipelines was counter intuitive and would also potentially require us to create custom tasks on the build agents to run the WiX CLI tools (heat.exe,  light.exe, candle.exe) against a version of our WXS file or have build steps that just built the wixproj file instead of the whole solution. However, I can see how this alternative approach may be suitable for others and I think is equally valid depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

What we did a few years back is maintaining a sub-folder that contains all the environment config files.  Using a Custom Action at install time and supplying that particular environment on the command line the custom action would extracts the config file from the environment matching folder in the `configFils.zip`.

Folder structure similar to this in the `ConfigFiles.zip` file.

```
/Dev1/app.config
/Dev2/app.config
/Prod/app.config

MsiExec.exe /i YourMSI.msi /TargetDir=C:\Yourfolder /Config=Prod
```

Custom action would extract and place the `app.config` from the Prod folder.

Comment: For an answer involving custom code that you have only referred to as a `Custom action` can you please post a code or config example of your custom action?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the release pipeline you've really only got a couple of choices:

1. Break the MSI apart and re-import the right config and repackage (don't know how easy this would be as I don't know MSI, but have taken this approach with other packages which are effectively `.zip`)
2. Build the package in the release pipeline. You say the files aren't available in the drop but you are in control of this from your build pipeline (assuming this was done with Azure Pipelines also). You can either change your pipeline therefore to copy the needed files (with a copy task) into the place you create your drop from which is usually `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. Alternatively if you don't want to mix these files into your drop you can create a second artifact drop (just put in another publish artifact task in for this). If I took this route I would copy the files that are in `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` today into `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/packagefiles` and the project files needed to package up the MSI into `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/projectfiles` and point the two publish artifacts tasks to either one of these directories.

Once you have the drops including the files to build your MSI you'll need tasks to replace in the right config and then an MSI packaging task and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

Instead of placing environment dependent settings in the App.config or any of its transforms, you could configure your app dynamically at runtime.

This would however require your app to get some clue from  the target system so that it knows in which environment or on which host it is running.

Example:
ASP.NET Core applications assume the existence of a „ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT“ environment variable. If it is not present, the applications assumes it runs in production.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Providing such an environment variable should‘t pose a problem when you have access to the hosts anyway.
Simply add a step at the beginning of your release pipeline to set up the environment variable and set its value to the name of the stage you’re trying to deploy to (development/testing/etc).

That way you can build your MSI once in the build pipeline and deploy on as much environments as you like.

Of course, this requires you to prepare your app for that target environment ahead of time.