Setup.msi - Copy file to the disk
I've two files on the USB drive :

Setup.msi (that includes the application setup)
Settings.ini

I want to copy Settings.ini to user's disk e.g. C:\ProgramData\MyApp\Settings.ini.
This is a one-time activity.
How do I do this ? The following code works stand-alone but the problem is how to get this executed once the setup is finished installation.

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    Console.WriteLine($"Folder '{path}' created successfully.");
}

string fileName = "myfile.txt";
string fullFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, fileName);

File.WriteAllText(fullFileName, createText);```


Are you packaging the setup.msi yourself? If so can you add a step to the installer to handle the file copying?

@IvanFurdek, I am just publishing the app in the folder and creating the MSI. Can you help me with the step handle the file copying ? Thanks

@IvanFurdek I just added this step using InstallAware. The file is copied successfully. However, there is no provision that the setup picks-up the file from the same folder the MSI is present. Any points will be highly appreciated.

The safest option is to include the file in the project so it is packed within the .msi.
It's even possible to modify it later on if needed without a rebuild - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126562/how-to-replace-a-file-in-a-msi-installer
Alternatively, you could add a step during instalation to pick the file, and then copy it to install dir.
Last option is to rely on the file always being in the same dir as installer.
I've not worked with that specific installer builder, so I can't help with specifics, sorry!

Used Inno Setup, which has out-of-box support for the C# Winforms application, and the setup can be scripted. Ref: Inno Setup copy file
